# Runtime.exec(cmd)'s user

Tags: java, linux, unix, runtime

When we run `Runtime.exec(cmd)`, what user will it be run from? For example, `user1`(on Unix) ran `java -jar Test.jar`. In this program we have `Runtime.exec("whoami")`. Which user id shall we recieve?

---

I have screen'd terminal, where was ran chrootuid cmd and there is running java program. And somehow, whoami command from this pr. returns **NOT SAME user id as chrootuid's owner**, from which name was J.p. ran. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: *'chrootuid's owner'* has nothing to do with it. It should run as the *newuser* supplied to *chrootuid.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SLaks says, the script will be run as the same user which has launched the JVM in the first place.

Rundown:

- the JVM is launched within a process;
- this process has plenty of data inherited from its parent, along which the user which launched it;
- the standard Java API has no way to modify the user;
- even if it had such power, changing the running user would require elevated privileges anyway.

So, there you are: the "forked" process will run with the same credentials as the JVM.

---

Now, some more information on running a separate process in general...

In Java, you really want to use a `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec()`, for the following reasons:

- it allows you to control I/O output;
- it allows you to specify command line arguments "the right way" (think: argument with spaces);
- it allows you to defer execution (`.start()`).

But it clearly does not allow you fine-grained control of shared resources, nor privilege modifications, as native APIs can do. Still, `ProcessBuilder` is better than `Runtime.exec()` by a large margin, but Java is yet to experience a radical change for process handling as the new `java.nio.file` is to `File`: a revolution.

Comment: Okay, I have `screen`'d terminal, where was ran `chrootuid` cmd and there is running java program. And somehow, whoami command from this pr. returns NOT SAME user id as chrootuid's owner, from which name was J.p. ran.

Comment: @user2781598 If that's part of your question it should be edited into your question, where everybody will see it.

Comment: Uh, OK, I just discovered the `chrootuid` command... Now, there are two kind of users in a process: the owner UID and the effective UID; according to the `whoami` manpage, the result is the effective UID. To be honest, it is quite some time since I've been dealing with process privileges at that level, to the extent that I don't even remind the real difference between the two!

Comment: @EJP Okay, do U have answer?

Comment: @fge Okay, but if I want to run some bash script (yeah, I'm pervert) from this program, but it requires owner privileges for this action, it's possible?

Comment: @user2781598 unsure what you really want; some more context is needed here. Anyway, if the permissions you need are that of the effective user of the JVM instance, since this will be inherited you won't have a problem.

Comment: @fge oh, effective user.. Can u explain what exactly does it mean?

Comment: @user2781598 OK well, this sort of question would better fit [superuser](https://superuser.com) really but here is a short example; take the `passwd` command: even if you run it as a "regular" user you have the ability to modify your password with it, and doing so requires elevated privileges. The program is owned by `root` and has the setuid bit set, as a result it will run with `root` as an _effective_ user; yet the modified password is yours, not root: the "real" user is you.

Answer (score 2):

All child processes run as the same user as the parent process.